# Is it possible to get access to Indeed API for an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, api, android-asynctask, retrofit2

I tried getting access to the Indeed API but it requires Indeed publisher account. Now to get publisher ID it's asking for website URL which I don't have as I need indeed API for Android application.

Is there any other replacement for Indeed API?